# onClick hierarchy

Tags: android

I'm creating some little sprites with a bmp inside the constructor of another view as background. But when I click the sprites, that have their onClickListener, the view I'm clicking is the background view.

Some code:

My constructor:

```
public ToposGameView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    moles = new ArrayList<MoleSprite>();
    setFocusable(true);
    setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i(tag, "Click en GameView");

        }
    });

    gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this);

    int id = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x<3; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y<4 ; y++){

            MoleSprite mole = new MoleSprite(this, x*WIDTH/3, HEIGHT/6+y*HEIGHT/6, FRONT);
            mole.setId(id);
            id++;
            moles.add(mole);
        }
    }

    holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
            boolean retry=true;
            gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
            while(retry){
                try{
                    gameLoopThread.join();
                    retry=false;

                }catch(InterruptedException i){

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
            gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);

            gameLoopThread.start();

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}
```

Sprite's constructor:

```
public MoleSprite(ToposGameView gameView, int x, int y, int direction) {
    super(gameView.getContext()); //TODO
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bad1);
    this.width = bmp.getWidth() / BMP_COLUMNS;      
    this.height = bmp.getHeight() / BMP_ROWS;

    this.x=x;
    this.y= y;

    this.setClickable(true);
    this.setFocusable(true);
    this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    setOnClickListener(this);
    setOnTouchListener(this);
    //I don't know what else to do!
    }
```

It's my first question, please ask me for more info.

Edit1:

```
public class MoleSprite extends View implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener{

public class ToposGameView extends SurfaceView{
```

Comment: What is the base class of the MoleSprite?  You're asking about onClick, which generally refers to the View hierarchy, but you're using SurfaceViews that represent rendering outside the view heirarchy.  There is some disconnect here, but too little info to identify it.

Comment: The idea is to do a game that needs redrawing but I'm jammed with the onClick. I edit with base classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mixing Surface drawing with View drawing.  Surfaces are great for rapid asynchronous redraws (such as games), but they are not View containers.  That is, there is no addView method on SurfaceView that is required for events and layouts.

As such, you will need to implement onClick handling on your SurfaceView and manually implement the detection of which Sprite is being clicked (e.g., is the click event within the sprite's x/y/width/height bounding box).

Also, it doesn't make sense for MoleSprite to extend View if used this way.  I expect you'll want to make your own Sprite base class to support the bounding boxes and drawing callbacks.  You can also add the onClick(..) interface to the Spirte base class, but you'll probably also want to keep separate lists for drawable/moveable/clickable items to optimize your list iterations as you develop your game.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you!! I'll implement the detection. Also, could you explain a little more the Sprite base class?

Comment: Current you're using View class as a superclass to manage the bounding rectangle and the draw callback, however, as I mentioned, you're not using it as a view.  Its kinda like looking at a rock, seeing it as moving object with enough mass to impact force, and thus calling it a hammer.  It can work, but its not an efficient hammer or have other attributes attributed to hammers like handles and nail pullers.  You can make a abstract base class called Spirte with methods getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight(), and onDraw() (for starters) to do exactly what you want with exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what your GameLoopThread is doing, but it should be calling your surface's onDraw method, and updatePhysics method.

the update physics will loop through your sprites and give them information, like the current game time, so they can move the proper distance, change the animation frame, or whatever.

for a sprite base class I use something like this (but mine handles animations, accelerations and other stuff):

```
public class Sprite {
    private Rect mScreenRect;
    public Sprite() {
        // init some stuff here, if you need it
        // especially, somewhere in your init functions 
        // set your bounding rect
        this.mScreenRect = Rect(xl, yt, xr, yb);
    }
    setStuff(int thing) {
      // like setX(), setY()
    }

    // here is the good stuff
    public boolean isTouched(int x, int y) {
        if(mScreenRect.contains(x, y))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    // also include a function to draw the graphic
    public void drawGraphic(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mScreenRect.left, mScreenRect.top, null);
    }
}
```

then, in your surface view you need to use the:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // this setup will move the sprite on the screen
    switch(event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if(sprite.isTouched(event.getX(), event.getY()) {
          // do your stuff
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        // handle the moving pointer
        sprite.setCoords(event.getX(), event.getY());
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        // handle the exiting pointer
        sprite.setCoords(event.getX(), event.getY());
        break;
    }
}
```

then in the surface view again:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    sprite.drawGraphic(canvas)
}
```

there are other posts that cover this in a more detailed manner, but this will get you started.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is a quite old question and it was already accepted. Thanks anyway!!